# Installator should either be a path to a local project or a VCS url beginning with svn+, git+, hg+, or bzr+

Tags: python, ros, ros2

I am trying to local install through pip using the following command:

```
# while positioned at the repository's root
pip3 install -e installator
```

and getting the following error:

```
Installator should either be a path to a local project or a VCS url beginning with svn+, git+, hg+, or bzr+
```

Answer (score 4):

You should do 
pip3 install -e git+YOUR-GITHUB-URL#egg=YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME 
example:

```
pip3 install -e git+https://github.com/user/repo.git#egg=mypackagename
```

REFERENCE and more docs: 
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#examples

Answer (score 4):

You can also try navigating to your home directory and give:

```
pip install -e .
```